# Selecting text in TextView and invoking floating menu on long-click

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu

I have a `TextView` with which I am trying to associate floating context menu activated on long-click. I need the text in the `TextView` to be selectable and once the selection is made (on long-click), the selected text to be used as input to the options in the floating context menu.
On long-pressing the `TextView`, the context menu shows up before the text selection range is displayed. This is different if I use the `Contextual Action Bar` menu instead, which gets invoked on long-press only after text has been selected on screen.

My question(s):
1. How do I ensure text selection mode is entered before the contextual menu is invoked?

```
package com.sriram.hellotts;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloTTS extends Activity {

    //ui elements.
    //private ImageButton playBtn;
    private Button playBtn;
    private TextView tv;

    private boolean longClick = false;
    private String chosenText;

    private int count = 1;

    private int REQUEST_RETURN_SETTINGS = 2;

    private static final int RECORDER_RETURN = 1;  //request code.

    //text to read.
    private String content = "MUMBAI: Whatever the general market trend, Mumbai's realty market does not stop " +
            "creating new records. In the costliest apartment deal in the country, a sea-facing duplex in a Malabar Hill" +
            " building was recently sold for Rs 57 crore or roughly Rs 1.35 lakh a sq ft., an increase of over 15% year on year." +
            " The duplex in the tony Darshan Apartments on Mount Pleasant Road was sold last month to the Bulchandanis," +
            " a prominent business family with interests in software, aluminium and real estate. They own three other duplexes " +
            "in the same complex. The family's latest acquisition (flat number 111) sits on the 9th, 10th and 11th floors of the " +
            "complex's 'A' wing, has four bedrooms and is spread over 3,510 sq ft. It comes with attached terraces of 1,386 sq ft " +
            "on the 11th and 12th floors and a covered garage of about 700 sq ft.\n" + 
            " NEW DELHI: A bunch of skulls of human ancestors dating back to 1.8 million years ago has created a storm among scientists." +
            "The discovery suggests that three human ancestor species were actually just one, with variations in features." + 
            " Five hominid skulls were found by scientists in Dmanisi, Georgia in 2005. The site is well-known for having revealed" +
            " a range of fossils. Of the five skulls, one was found to fit with a jaw bone found in 2000 at the same site." + 
            " This fitting together gave rise to a complete skull. Informally known as \"skull 5\", it \"is the most complete skull" +
            " of an adult from this date\", says Marcia Ponce de Leon, of the Anthropological Institute and Museum in Zurich, Switzerland," + 
            " and one of the authors of the study.";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_tts);

        //prevent window from going to sleep.
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //hierarchical navigation.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //get ui elements and add relevant functionality.
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        //set other features for textview.
        tv.setFocusable(true);


        Log.v(this.toString(), "Setting content for textview: " + content);
        tv.setText(content);

        tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Long click of EditText.");
                tv.setCursorVisible(true);
                longClick = true;

                //if the TTS is speaking, pause it.
                if(TTS != null) {
                    if(TTS.isSpeaking()) {
                        TTS.pause();
                    }
                }

                //bring up our custom action mode menu.
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Starting actionmodecallback.");
                v.setSelected(true);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

registerForContextMenu(tv);

```
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction();

                /* 
                 * On action up,if longClick was active, then chosenText etc. are taken in.
                 */

                switch(action) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Action down.");
                break;

                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Action up.");
                if(longClick) {
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Action up after long click. Getting to selecting text.");
                    int start = tv.getSelectionStart();
                    int end = tv.getSelectionEnd();
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Start = " + start + " and end = " + end);
                    chosenText = tv.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
                }
                longClick = false;  //reset longClick.

                break;

                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Action move.");
                break;

                default:
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Some other activity seen which is not being handled.");
                break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo adcm = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        boolean result = false;
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.option1:
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Option 1 chosen.");
            result = true;
            break;

        case R.id.readFromHere:
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Read from here.");
            result = true;
            break;

        default:
            result = super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The options menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:id="@+id/readFromHere"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/readFromHere" />

      <item android:id="@+id/option1"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/record" />   
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Activity with `android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT`.

This will add an option in floating menu, just as shown here: [Custoom floating toolbar for text selection controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768857/custoom-floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-controls)