# Custoom floating toolbar for text selection controls

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to customize the floating toolbar that appears when you select a text.

This is an example of the standard floating toolbar:

[image: Floating Toolbar example].

Do you know how I can customize it (like adding Bold, Italic,...)? Is there an external library?

The Monospace app has exactly what I want:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You’ll add an intent filter to an Activity in your manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>`
```

Comment: this only adds an option, that is also visible when user selects text in another app