# How to show built-in horizontal edit menu on custom EditText view

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to easily show a simple menu, similar to this one in a screenshot from Chrome? I want a menu to show when there is a selection to manipulate to allow the user to Slect All, Cut, Copy, Paste.

[image: example horizontal floating menu]

Is this a standard control or something that should be easy to get working? What is the name of this control. This control is not showing automatically for our custom EditText view, which is fully functional in every other way.

Will I have to create my own custom control and display it in the correct location, manually? I have done similar work for an equivalent custom control in iOS, where the menu I want is called an Edit Menu, and it is trivial to show and hide that menu.

Comment: Related questions that ask for different requirements but sound related, that aren't really pointing me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673185/disable-edittext-context-menu , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768857/custoom-floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-controls